# In volley post request i m adding a comment parameter in url but it takes only one word and space is not allowed

Tags: android

```
final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url+ "Id=" + Id + "&status=true&CompletedTime=" + Time + "&Comment=" + commentTxt,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String resp) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

It works when:

`commentTxt=test`

it doesn't work when:

`commentTxt=test test`

Comment: try to pass hashmap for get url also !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your url. So you will get the exact result:

```
try {
    String url = url+ "Id=" + Id + "&status=true&CompletedTime=" + Time + "&Comment=" + commentTxt;
    String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
    Log.d("TEST", encodedurl);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please take a look. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to encode the `commentTxt` so that any "spaces" can be converted to valid url like this

```
String comment= URLEncoder.encode(commentTxt, "utf-8");
String url = url+ "Id=" + Id + "&status=true&CompletedTime=" + Time + "&Comment=" + comment;
```

and then ask your backend developer to decode `commentTxt`